# javascript date to java date field

Tags: java, javascript, date

I have a javascript date stored as a String in java. for example: `1327680000000`
I want to convert this date from javascript to java date field.

I want it to get displayed in a specific format like `"Jan 30 12:25:22"` or something like this.

Comment: Is this javascript date in milliseconds?

Comment: @thinksteep: Based on the value, yeah. 1327680000000 is Fri Jan 27 2012 16:00:00 GMT assuming milliseconds-since-The-Epoch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript dates and Java dates both share a common characteristic: Their underlying value is the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st, 1970 at midnight GMT). Looking at the value you've given, it looks like that's the value you have in your string. So to convert it to a Java date, [parse the string as a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and use the [`Date(long)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29):

```
Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(theString, 10));
```

Then you can use a `DateFormat` implementation like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or similar to format it; you might also use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object for handling timezones and such.

Comment: @thinksteep: No, but you use it as part of the overall formatting solution if you want to handle timezones correctly. The phrasing was poor, though, agreed.